# Learning about splicing, but after splicing my spawn function returns undefined, why?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Started learning how to program last week and began with the P5 library/Javascript. I decided t make a program that spawns bubbles randomly and 'pops' or is removed from the array after it reaches a certain radius. However, after half of my max bubbles are removed my spawn() function return undefined and the other half remain on screen.

Link to code: [Here](https://editor.p5js.org/contactyosue/sketches/U6akUJ71O)

Previously I tried but found that it just sets the radius to zero and loops.

```
  if (bubble[i].r > 200){
    bubble[i].r = 0;
  }
```

So after some researching I found out about splice() did the following.

```
  if (bubble[i].r > 200){
      bubble.splice(i, 1);
  }
```

From what I understand it takes the selected value from my array 'bubble' and checks if the radius is ever greater than 200 and if it is, it takes that selected value and removes it by one space only. And it does work but only ever for half of whatever my counter max is which I don't understand why...

```
let bubble = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  let x = random(width);
  let y = random(height);
  bubble[i] = new Bubble(x, y, 0);
  }
  
}

function draw() {
  
  background(0);
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  bubble[i].spawn();
  bubble[i].update();
  
  if (bubble[i].r > 200){
    bubble.splice(i, 1);
    print('removed');
  }
  
  }
  
}

//CLASSES

class Bubble {
  
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.r = r;  
    
  }
  
  spawn() {
    circle(this.x, this.y, this.r);
    noFill();
    stroke(255);
    
  }
  
  update() {
    this.r += 5;
      
  }
  
}
```

Error

```
 p5.js says: 
[sketch.js, line 18] Cannot read property of undefined. Check the line number in error and make sure the variable which is being operated is not undefined.

 + More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_property#what_went_wrong
```

Comment: @Konrad Please don't insert code from external resource. It's a copyright problem.

Comment: @jabaa why not?

Comment: @Konrad The author has to do this. It's not your code. There is a description somewhere in the help center. I'll try to find it.

Comment: Edited my post to follow that format, seems better! Sorry I'm newwww

Comment: @Konrad I found this, but I remember something better. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275485/copy-large-code-block-from-external-source-to-an-answer-to-secure-it

Comment: @jabaa makes sense legally, but it makes this site worse for new users

Comment: You learned one important lesson: Don't modify (add elements to or remove elements from) a container you're iterating over.

Comment: @Konrad You can write a comment for the OP to copy and insert the code into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The error says `Cannot read property of undefined` meaning that `bubble[i]` is `undefined`

You've used splice to remove an element, but you didn't reduce the index

```
for (let i = 0; i < bubble.length; i++) {
  bubble[i].spawn();
  bubble[i].update();
  
  if (bubble[i].r > 200){
    bubble.splice(i, 1);
    print('removed');
    i -= 1
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little. When removing something from the array, it is better to start by the end of the array and then decrement the index. This way, for example, when you remove element at index 5, the loop will go to index 4, which does exist for sure.

I added 'amount' variable, for some more dynamic testing.

```js
let bubble = [];
const amount = 10;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++)
  {
    let x = random(width);
    let y = random(height);
    bubble[i] = new Bubble(x, y, 0);
  }
  
}

function draw() {
  
  background(0);
  
  for (let i = bubble.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    bubble[i].spawn();
    bubble[i].update();

    if (bubble[i].r > 200)
    {
      bubble.splice(i, 1);
      print('removed');
    }
  }
  
}

//CLASSES

class Bubble {
  
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.r = r;  
    
  }
  
  spawn() {
    circle(this.x, this.y, this.r);
    noFill();
    stroke(255);
    
  }
  
  update() {
    this.r += 5;
      
  }
  
}
```